# Full page images on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am sorry for not trying anything yet but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. I have this menu:

```
<div class="overlay-navigation">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="test">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-content=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#three" class="scrollTo" data-content="">tutorials</li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank" data-content="">my creations</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#four" class="scroll" data-content="">contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-content=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

When I click on my creations, I want a simple full screen image caroussel, gallery or flexbox to appear (whatever looks better, the menu opens at full screen) that's easy to close. I would appreciate any code examples so I can style it to my liking, I will only have about 4 images.

Comment: This is usually called a "lightbox". Try searching for that term.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Tried to implement this and it looks really good, thank you! @therealbischero

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boostrap carousel. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup) or lightbox can help you out.